# jquery not loading fully before page loads

Tags: jquery, wordpress, loading, bandwidth

I have a wordpress website that although works is not loading fully in a large office where the bandwidth is limited to each machine. so when the website loads in such a location it does not load all of the jquery and thus we have display issue. The browser used in that office is IE 7 and 8. i've tested the site on my version of IE 7 and 8 and all looks fine with no script errors which makes me think it has to be bandwidth stopping the scripts form loading.

So i guess my question is how do we preload scripts that are being added via plugins in wordpress?

Comment: include jquery.js in the <head> tag of the html

Comment: there seems to be some jquery being added in the body of the page by plugins which seem sot be causing the issue

Comment: Hard to help without some specific information.

Comment: this is the website www.corestream.co.uk
i dont know how you would test this without a low bandwidth conection.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to avoid asset conflicts and in your case, loading the scripts first and sequentially is by properly enqueueing the files. To do this you must use [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

a good way to do this is to put it as part of a function in your functions.php file like so

1. create a function
2. insert `wp_register_script` into the function
3. then insert `wp_enqeue_script` into the function
4. use add_action(), to initlize the enqueue-ing process

---

so -

```
function load_scripts() {
  wp_register_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array( 'scriptyouwillwaittobeloaded' ) );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name' );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');
```

---

In this example the function `load_scripts()` would then be called in the header.php file. Take a look at [wp_register_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) as well to get a better understanding of the arguments for that as well, but in summary -

first argument: is the name you want to use as reference to this script

second argument: is the actual link to the script

third argument: is the script that you want to load before this script (the script you want to wait for before this script loads)

---

and for wp_enqueue_script, the argument is merely a reference to the name (the first argument of wp_register_script)

---

**the add_action function arguments:**

first argument: the function you are "hooking" into

second argument: the function you created that will be "hooked"